# Multiple Repeat error when submitting a django form containing char field for phone number

Tags: python, django, forms

I am a beginner in django/python. I have created a charfield in my django model for storing phone number of user. I have provided a regex validator for validating entries made by user but when I submit the form it gives multiple repeat error. I am not sure why this error comes. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the model:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    account_company_name = models.ForeignKey('Account', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='account_id')
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Contact name', max_length=120, blank=False, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True, db_column='Email', blank=False, null=False)
    phone = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10,validators = [RegexValidator(r'\d{10}+|\d{5}([- ]*)\d{6}')],\
        db_column='Phone', blank=False, null=False)
    notes = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Contact'
```

Here is the forms.py file:

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['account_company_name', 'name', 'email', 'phone', 'notes']
```

Here is the error Traceback as requested:

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\admin_hp\crm_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\admin_hp\crm_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\admin_hp\crm_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "G:\PycharmProjects\crm\crm_app\views.py" in add_contact
  43.         if form.is_valid():

File "C:\Users\admin_hp\crm_env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in is_valid
  183.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "C:\Users\admin_hp\crm_env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in errors
  175.             self.full_clean()

File "C:\Users\admin_hp\crm_env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  386.         self._post_clean()

File "C:\Users\admin_hp\crm_env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in _post_clean
  396.             self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)

File "C:\Users\admin_hp\crm_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in full_clean
  1226.             self.clean_fields(exclude=exclude)

File "C:\Users\admin_hp\crm_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in clean_fields
  1268.                 setattr(self, f.attname, f.clean(raw_value, self))

File "C:\Users\admin_hp\crm_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in clean
  603.         self.run_validators(value)

File "C:\Users\admin_hp\crm_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in run_validators
  555.                 v(value)

File "C:\Users\admin_hp\crm_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\validators.py" in __call__
  60.         if not (self.inverse_match is not bool(self.regex.search(

File "C:\Users\admin_hp\crm_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in inner
  238.             self._setup()

File "C:\Users\admin_hp\crm_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in _setup
  385.         self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()

File "C:\Users\admin_hp\crm_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\validators.py" in _compile
  24.             return re.compile(regex, flags)

File "C:\Users\admin_hp\crm_env\lib\re.py" in compile
  194.     return _compile(pattern, flags)

File "C:\Users\admin_hp\crm_env\lib\re.py" in _compile
  251.         raise error, v # invalid expression

Exception Type: error at /crmbasic/addcontact/
Exception Value: multiple repeat
```

Comment: can you provide the error message

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace, also dont include a link to an image, copy paste it as text data??

Comment: As requested ,I have added the full traceback of the error. @FazilZaid

Comment: Your regex is invalid.  Put a valid regex

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is invalid. I do not know your required format but may be this is what you are looking for

```
phone = models.CharField(
    primary_key=True,
    max_length=12,
    validators=RegexValidator(r"^\d{10}|(\d{5}[\-]\d{6})$")], 
    db_column='Phone',
    blank=False,
    null=False)
```